# Publish subscribe implementation with Spring JMS

Tags: spring, jboss, jndi, spring-jms

I have a JMS queue implementation with `JmsTemplate`. I want to have more than one listener when a message is put in the queue, i.e. I want to use topic instead of queue.

I have configuration without JMS namespacing. What are the changes that need to be made to have multiple listeners listen on a topic when someone sends a message in a topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are probably using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. Just to be sure, you want that several individual components receive the **same** message (i.e. you don't want to process messages in parallel).

Assuming I got this right and component A and compoent B should receive the same message, you simply create two `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` instance on the same topic and you set the `pubSubDomain` property to `true`. Make sure you haven't set any concurrency on the listener container, or better yet, set the concurrency to 1 to make that explicit.

This would give something like

```
<bean id="listener1"
      class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
    <property name="concurrency" value="1"/>
    <property name="destinationName=" value="...."/> <!-- topic name -->
    <property name="messageListener" ref="...."/> 
</bean>
```

Then you should create a similar bean for the second component.